# ElasticSearch Java Client querying "Double" nested objects

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I have elastic nested  data like this.
For the property, `best_practice` got single nested query,
property `work_field` got double nested query.

I want to convert query for double nested structure(about `work_field`) to Java code

```
"_source": {
    "best_practice": [
        {
            "code": "A002",
            "best_practice_summary": "a",
            "best_practice_type": "AAA"
        },
        {
            "code": "A001",
            "best_practice_summary": "s",
            "best_practice_type": "BBB"
        }
    ],
    "work_field": {
        "choice_field": [
            {
                "isSelected": true,
                "idx": 1,
                "value": "CCC",
                "key": "B002"
            },
            {
                "isSelected": true,
                "idx": 77,
                "value": "DDD",
                "key": "B078"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This java code works for single nested query(`best_practice.code`), but it doensn't for double query.
How can i convert it for double nested?

```
public NestedQueryBuilder nestedBoolQuery(final Map<String, String> propertyValues, final String nestedPath) {

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    Iterator<String> iterator = propertyValues.keySet().iterator();
    propertyValues.put("work_field.choice_field.key", "B002");

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String propertyName = iterator.next();
        String propertValue = propertyValues.get(propertyName);
        MatchQueryBuilder matchQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(propertyName, propertValue);
        boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery);
    }

    return QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(nestedPath, boolQueryBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find snippet of working code below (using the Rest High Level Client):

good luck,

Wim

```
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("useCase", useCase));
    boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("customerId", customerId));

    sourceBuilder.query(boolQuery).size(SIZE_OF_ES_QUERY_RESULT);
    sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(retrieveEventsTimeOutValueInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest().source(sourceBuilder);

    searchResponse = restClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
    .....
```

Comment: thx for replying but,,
i guess you suggested your example as non nested structure.

my problem is that i have to find a 'key' property in the 'choice_filed' which is belong to 'work_field'

Comment: curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:9200/stackoverflow_20210207/best_practices/_count -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "best_practice.code.keyword": "A002"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "match": {
            "work_field.choice_field.key.keyword": "B078"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
' | json_pp

Answer (score 0):

Please find example of the query below (same logic as in my first answer but focussed entirely on your index). I search on best_practice.code AND on work_field.choice_field.key. Query works perfectly. Use this example and apply it in your Java code. Should work without any problem.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:9200/stackoverflow_20210207/best_practices/_count -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "best_practice.code.keyword": "A002"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "match": {
            "work_field.choice_field.key.keyword": "B078"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
' | json_pp
```